# I can't do transformation on a RDD[ConsumerRecord]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a serialization problem with a ConsumerRecord recover from a kafka topic in a DStream. To illustrate my problem, I create the following exemple. I create a ConsumerRecord with a json value, I put it inside a rdd. I do a collect in order to print result. I get a serialization error. here is the Exemple:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
object Exemple {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("Exemple")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val consumerRecord:  ConsumerRecord[String, String] = new  ConsumerRecord("",1,2l,"myTopic","""{"id":1}""")
    val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(consumerRecord))
    val valueRDD = rdd.map(cr => cr.value)
    valueRDD.collect.foreach(println) // this line throws error

  }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 0) / 4]18/03/02 00:58:55 ERROR Utils: Exception encountered
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:441)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition$$anonfun$writeObject$1.apply$mcV$sp(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition$$anonfun$writeObject$1.apply(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition$$anonfun$writeObject$1.apply(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1303)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition.writeObject(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1028)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager$$anonfun$resourceOffer$1.apply(TaskSetManager.scala:472)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager$$anonfun$resourceOffer$1.apply(TaskSetManager.scala:453)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager.resourceOffer(TaskSetManager.scala:453)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$TaskSchedulerImpl$$resourceOfferSingleTaskSet$1.apply$mcVI$sp(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:295)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.org$apache$spark$scheduler$TaskSchedulerImpl$$resourceOfferSingleTaskSet(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:290)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl$$anonfun$resourceOffers$4$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:375)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl$$anonfun$resourceOffers$4$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:373)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl$$anonfun$resourceOffers$4.apply(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl$$anonfun$resourceOffers$4.apply(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:370)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.resourceOffers(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:370)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint.reviveOffers(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcV$sp(Inbox.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.safelyCall(Inbox.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.process(Inbox.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher$MessageLoop.run(Dispatcher.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
18/03/02 00:58:55 ERROR Utils: Exception encountered
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:441)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition$$anonfun$writeObject$1.apply$mcV$sp(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition$$anonfun$writeObject$1.apply(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition$$anonfun$writeObject$1.apply(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1303)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition.writeObject(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1028)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visitSerializableWithWriteObjectMethod(SerializationDebugger.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visitSerializable(SerializationDebugger.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visit(SerializationDebugger.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visitSerializable(SerializationDebugger.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visit(SerializationDebugger.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.find(SerializationDebugger.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager$$anonfun$resourceOffer$1.apply(TaskSetManager.scala:472)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager$$anonfun$resourceOffer$1.apply(TaskSetManager.scala:453)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager.resourceOffer(TaskSetManager.scala:453)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$TaskSchedulerImpl$$resourceOfferSingleTaskSet$1.apply$mcVI$sp(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:295)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.org$apache$spark$scheduler$TaskSchedulerImpl$$resourceOfferSingleTaskSet(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:290)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl$$anonfun$resourceOffers$4$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:375)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl$$anonfun$resourceOffers$4$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:373)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl$$anonfun$resourceOffers$4.apply(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl$$anonfun$resourceOffers$4.apply(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:370)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.resourceOffers(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:370)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint.reviveOffers(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcV$sp(Inbox.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.safelyCall(Inbox.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.process(Inbox.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher$MessageLoop.run(Dispatcher.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
18/03/02 00:58:55 ERROR TaskSetManager: Failed to serialize task 3, not attempting to retry it.
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord, value: ConsumerRecord(topic = , partition = 1, offset = 2, NoTimestampType = -1, checksum = -1, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = -1, key = myTopic, value = {"id":1}))
    - element of array (index: 0)
    - array (class [Lorg.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;, size 1)
    - field (class: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef, name: array, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
    - object (class scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef, WrappedArray(ConsumerRecord(topic = , partition = 1, offset = 2, NoTimestampType = -1, checksum = -1, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = -1, key = myTopic, value = {"id":1})))
    - writeObject data (class: org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition, org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition@694)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask, name: partition, type: interface org.apache.spark.Partition)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask, ResultTask(0, 3))
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager$$anonfun$resourceOffer$1.apply(TaskSetManager.scala:472)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager$$anonfun$resourceOffer$1.apply(TaskSetManager.scala:453)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager.resourceOffer(TaskSetManager.scala:453)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$TaskSchedulerImpl$$resourceOfferSingleTaskSet$1.apply$mcVI$sp(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:295)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.org$apache$spark$scheduler$TaskSchedulerImpl$$resourceOfferSingleTaskSet(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:290)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl$$anonfun$resourceOffers$4$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:375)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl$$anonfun$resourceOffers$4$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:373)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl$$anonfun$resourceOffers$4.apply(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl$$anonfun$resourceOffers$4.apply(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:370)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.resourceOffers(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:370)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint.reviveOffers(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcV$sp(Inbox.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.safelyCall(Inbox.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.process(Inbox.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher$MessageLoop.run(Dispatcher.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
18/03/02 00:58:55 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Resource offer failed, task set TaskSet_0.0 was not serializable
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Failed to serialize task 3, not attempting to retry it. Exception during serialization: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord, value: ConsumerRecord(topic = , partition = 1, offset = 2, NoTimestampType = -1, checksum = -1, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = -1, key = myTopic, value = {"id":1}))
    - element of array (index: 0)
    - array (class [Lorg.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;, size 1)
    - field (class: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef, name: array, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
    - object (class scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef, WrappedArray(ConsumerRecord(topic = , partition = 1, offset = 2, NoTimestampType = -1, checksum = -1, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = -1, key = myTopic, value = {"id":1})))
    - writeObject data (class: org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition, org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition@694)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask, name: partition, type: interface org.apache.spark.Partition)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask, ResultTask(0, 3))
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1499)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1487)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1714)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1669)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1658)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2022)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2043)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2062)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2087)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:936)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:935)
    at Exemple$.main(Exemple.scala:20)
    at Exemple.main(Exemple.scala)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: The error is straightforward. It simply means that `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord` is not serializable meaning that `ConsumerRecord` class doesn't extend serializable. What you can do is extend `ConsumerRecord`class in your own class and extend the new class as serializable.

Comment: ...or use `case class SomeRecord` to represent data in RDD

Comment: I think i misunderstood something. Spark streaming using the KafkaConsumer will give me a Dstream (a flow of RDD[ConsumerRecord]). I can't process a map to get the value of each ConsumerRecord foreach RDD since ConsumerRecord is not serializable. So I need to make an implementation with Kryo. But in the Spark documentation, the last line of the first exemple map the key and the value of the ConsumerRecord. I am a little bit confused: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord is not serializable, So there are some way to solve this kind of problems

1. Serializable the class using kryo serialization
2. Declare the instance only within the lambda function passed in map.
3. Make the NotSerializable object as a static and create it once per machine.
4. Call rdd.forEachPartition and create the NotSerializable object in there like this:

   rdd.forEachPartition(iter -> {
     NotSerializable notSerializable = new NotSerializable();

   // ...Now process iter
   });

For more details you can check this link https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/troubleshooting/javaionotserializableexception.html

Comment: I think i misunderstood something. Spark streaming using the KafkaConsumer will give me a Dstream (a flow of RDD[ConsumerRecord]). I can't process a map to get the value of each ConsumerRecord foreach RDD since ConsumerRecord is not serializable. So I need to make an implementation with Kryo. But in the Spark documentation, the last line of the first exemple map the key and the value of the ConsumerRecord. I am a little bit confused: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html

Comment: So, As you mention in the code the its not spark streaming its a spark core, so if you create ConsumerRecord object itself you notice its a normal class so it not serialize by default its not a case class. According to spark docs https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html the spark streaming give you the object of Consumer Record, So if you use spark streaming it should work but if you specifically create object you need to make it serializable somehow!